Congestion Control in Datagram subnet: warning bit method vs choke packet
What is the difference between warning bit method and method of sending choke packets?
Wherein both the methods deals by sending a signal that tells the transmitter about the congestion occurred in the sub-net.

I found this with just a simple Google search
